# Italicizing strip.text with plotly/ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I've been trying to use ggplot2 and the ggplotly function from the "plotly" library in R to make a faceted grid with italicized labels on y-axis and just can't seem to make it to happen.

Here I'll use the "Free Y Axis" example of a faceted grid as written by Plotly:
https://plotly.com/ggplot2/facet_grid/

The only change I've made to this code is make the strip text for both axes larger and the y-axis text italicized in the ggplot theme().

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=2,colour="white")

# With panels that have the same scaling, but different range (and therefore different physical sizes)
p <- p + facet_grid(sex ~ smoker, scales="free", space="free") +
              theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size=13),
                    strip.text.y=element_text(size=13,face="italic"))

p

fig <- ggplotly(p)

fig
```

The plot produced by ggplot (p) looks like this, with the y-axis facet labels in italics:
[ggplot with proper italicization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMSa6.png)

The plot produced by ggplotly (fig) looks like this:
[ggplotly with no italicization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leFHx.png)

Comment: Hi there, your imgur links don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the data in `p`, adding html tags for italics

```r
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=2,colour="white")

p <- p + facet_grid(sex ~ smoker, scales="free", space="free") +
    theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size=13),
          strip.text.y=element_text(size=13, face="italic"))

p$data$sex <- paste0("<i>", p$data$sex, "</i>")
fig <- ggplotly(p) 
fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, glad I could help (although it is a somewhat hack-ish approach, and I would love to learn if there was a more formal way to achieve this). As a general rule, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for future questions.